# How can I make this UIBarButtonItem Bold?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I need to make this UIBarButtonItem text bold. I sound fairly simple but I cannot figure it out.

```
let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(moveToSecond))
```

Comment: Change style to `.done`

Comment: Perfect! It worked, do you know if it's possible to make the whole navigation bar a little bigger, in terms of its height?

Comment: I saw some other post saying that this was not possible in iOS 11 Xcode 9

Comment: Glad it worked. I’m sure that is possible but I’m afraid it’s beyond my knowledge at present. You could try asking a new question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple solution is to change the style of the `UIBarButtonItem` to `.done`

Answer (score 19):

`UIBarButtonItem` extends `UIBarItem`. `UIBarItem` has the `setTitleTextAttributes` function. Use that to set a bold font.

```
let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(moveToSecond))
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [ .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16) ]
nextButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

This also lets you set other attributes if needed such as color, underline, and pretty much anything supported by an attributed string.

Of course simply setting the `style` to `.done` instead of `.plain` may also give you the desired results. The downside to this approach is that there is no guarantee that `.done` will be rendered as bold. That could change in any iOS update.

Comment: Upvoted. This is a more flexible answer than mine, allowing more control over font etc.

Comment: "The downside to this approach is that there is no guarantee that .done will be rendered as bold." - Or that could be an upside. If the reason for being bold is to match the iOS look and feel for a Done button, inheriting any such change across iOS versions is a good thing.